# .ni.dll files in silverlight directory

Tags: c#, silverlight

What is the *.ni.dll files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.10411.0" directory? 
And What is the deference between .ni.dll files and .dll files?
And why .ni.dll files are bigger?.

```
system.dll : 234kb ---- System.ni.dll : 649kb
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll : 425kb ---- System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll : 1,137kb
System.Windows.dll : 1,883kb ---- System.Windows.ni.dll : 4,886kb
System.Xml.dll : 313kb ---- System.Xml.ni.dll : 805kb
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are native images for assemblies.  .dll contains IL code, .ni.dll contains native code.

See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/11/11/256122.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`.ni.dll` files are the *native image* of the Silverlight DLL. The DLLs, represented in managed code, are compiled to native code during the SL installation, so that they can have a better runtime performance.

Comment: thank you. you right files for native code. but not only for performance. check out @Kieren Johnstone link.